# How to line tables up nicely in html/css on a webpage

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I'm having problem aligning my tables the same on one page: http://sites.northwestern.edu/mrsec/people/faculty/
The first table is the long row of people, but then I made another table, and it shifted to the right a little and the table after that shifted to th right. I want the tables to be aligned the same, have one directly underneath the other without any indentation.

Here is my code for the table and it's the same for each table minus changes in urls.

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;" margin-left:-20px; border="0"     
 width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
 <tbody> <tr> 
 <td style="border:none"> <a href=""> <img src="" alt="" /> </a> 
 </td> 
 <td style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;text-align:left;vertical-       
  align:middle;margin-left:-10px"> <a href="" target="_blank"> Gabriela  
  Gonzalez Aviles</a> | <em>Physics</em></td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Friendly: DO NOT USE TABLE! that's all!

Comment: Your entire HTML is a mess. It's not the tables that are faulty. I'd consider a rewrite of this entire page. Try to stick to a framework conversion (like bootstrap), it will make your life a lot easier...